# swipe ListView inside a ViewPager?

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, swipe

I know this is sort of broad question, and I googled a lot, also on StackOverflow I tried to find a solution but didn't find what I want, or the solutions didn't work.

I have a `ViewPager` inside which I have a `listView`. Now all I want is make `listView` swipeable regardless of my `viewPager`, so when I swipe the `listView`, I can decide to do something other than swiping to a new `View`. I set a `SwipeListener` to my `listView` like below:

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

protected OnSwipeTouchListener(Context ctx) {
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}

public void onSwipeRight() {
}

public void onSwipeLeft() {
}

public void onSwipeTop() {
}

public void onSwipeBottom() {
}

private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 23;
    private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 0;

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
            float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffX > 0) {
                        onSwipeRight();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeLeft();
                    }
                    result = true;
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
}
```

Inside my `fragment`:

```
OnSwipeTouchListener onSwipeTouchListener = new OnSwipeTouchListener(context) {
        public void onSwipeRight() {

        }

        public void onSwipeLeft() {

        }
    };
listView.setOnTouchListener(onSwipeTouchListener);
```

But this doesn't make my `listView` swipeable. I used test point and understood that `onFling()` method is not called. Also although `onDown()` method is called, but changing its return value doesn't change any behavior of my `listView. So what is the trick?

Comment: Are `ListView` and `ViewPager` both of same height ? If yes then i think you should use `NonSwipableViewPager`.

Comment: Obviously no! There are also other items beside listView inside the fragment which is set up with FragmentStatePagerAdapter. @ADM

Comment: Well then you need to disallow the touch. See the uses of `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent()`.

Comment: I set listView.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true), but it still doesn't work. Note that onDown() is called inside SimpleOnGestureListener, but onFling() is not called.